# getting likes to show up on news feeds

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am writing to find out if this is possible and clarification.

I am looking to develop a site that has many business's, and obviously incorporate FB like buttons where consumers can click like. Now how do I incorporate where it will actually show on peoples news feed, where "john does likes xyz company on www.mysite.com"?

I understand it will show on there wall but how do I get it to show up on the feed to attract more users to my site?

Is this possible anymore with FB?